# How to make a fixed header with a fixed side menu with element-ui

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I want to make a fixed header with a fixed menu also, with the header being on top and the menu taking up the rest of the height of the page, this is my current code for my layout vue file.

Currently my header is good but the menu is not the full height of the rest of the page. How can I make the menu work and be fixed to the side without it being weird and not the incorrect size, I've tried to add a fixed height and then I get a weird tiny amount of scroll which I don't want.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
<template>
    <el-container class="main-layout">
        <el-header>
            <el-row style="margin-top: 0.5%">
                <el-col>
                    <el-dropdown trigger="click" class="fa-pull-right">
                        <el-button
                            class="logout"
                            icon="el-icon-arrow-down">
                            user
                        </el-button>
                        <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
                            <a href="/logout">
                                <el-dropdown-item>Logout</el-dropdown-item>
                            </a>
                        </el-dropdown-menu>
                    </el-dropdown>
                </el-col>
            </el-row>
        </el-header>
        <el-aside class="el-menu-layout" style="padding: 0; width: auto;">
            <el-menu :gutter="8" :xs="2" :label="true" @open="handleOpen" @close="handleClose"
                     :collapse="collapse()"
                     :unique-opened="true"
                     style="height: 100%">
                <el-menu-item>
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    User
                </el-menu-item>
            </el-menu>
        </el-aside>
        <div class="main-container">
            <slot class="mt-1"></slot>
        </div>
    </el-container>
</template>
```

This is my css for the classes mentioned here

```
.el-menu-layout {
    background: $gray-1 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.el-header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 12%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `position:fixed` you could place something fixed, keep in mind that you also have to set the position of the parent element. Css should be like this:

```
.main-layout {
  position: relative;
}

.el-menu-layout {
    position: fixed;
    background: grey !important;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.el-header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    height: 12%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.main-container {
  margin-top:60px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```